# Excel VBA: Way to find the value of a cell with multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel, find

I have a large file that contain 3 columns and 23393 rows in a sheet. columns A refer to date, column B refer to integer numbers and the third column refer to value.
I want to find the value of a cell (in third column) with multiple criteria.

1)the first criteria is a date (it changes from 1/1/2008 to 12/31/2009)

2)the second criteria is an integer number(it changes from 1 to 32)

Thanks

Comment: formula `=INDEX(H2:H23393,MATCH(DATEVALUE("1/1/2008")&F2,D2:D23393&F2:F23393,0))`              Its output is the value I want , but I want run it in macro and the output of the formula goes to an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about the simple approach?

```
Function find(ByVal criteria1 As Date, ByVal criteria2 As Integer) As Variant

    For i = 2 To 300001
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = criteria1 Then
            If Cells(i, 2).Value = criteria2 Then
                find = Cells(i, 3).Value
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    find = "N/A"

End Function
```

You can test it running a simple macro like this:

```
Sub storeFoundValues()

    Dim matches(2) As Variant
    Dim date1, date2 As Date
    Dim int1, int2 As Integer

    date1 = DateSerial(2015, 7, 15)
    int1 = 3
    matches(1) = find(date1, int1)
    Cells(1, 5) = matches(1) ' test the output

    date2 = DateSerial(2016, 1, 10)
    int2 = 2
    matches(2) = find(date2, int2)
    Cells(1, 6) = matches(2) ' test the output

End Sub
```

This took less than a second in a worksheet with 30.000 records.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @carlossierra

Comment: Just a question,  How can I use date in loop ? I mean in my code I assigned date as dd/mm/yyyy and not yyyy,mm,dd . Do you have any solution ?

Comment: If the date is hardcoded, I suggest you use the approach I followed, because it's safer (it's going to return the correct results no matter the user locale). Or if you get the date directly from a cell in your worksheet, I think it is safe to just get the cell value and pass it to the function.

Comment: no the date is not hard coded, and I dont get the date directly from cells. I just need to assign date in a loop  with the dd/mm/yyyy format . when I use this format in the ِِDateSerial function, "compile error" occurs.

Comment: @MajidJavanmard my suggestion is to add another question showing your assignment code (in the loop), because it's difficult to provide more feedback without looking at it (I don't understand why the `DateSerial(var1, var2, var3)` won't work here...

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
=INDEX(C1:C20,SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A20=DATEVALUE("6/17/2009"))*(B1:B20=25)*ROW(1:20)))
```

[image]

This approach assumes that only one row will match the criteria.

Comment: Thanks for your answer how can I write it in macro and write its output to a string array : `=INDEX(H2:H23393,MATCH(DATEVALUE("1/1/2008")&F2,D2:D23393&F2:F23393,0))`

Comment: would you please answer my question !?

Comment: @MajidJavanmard  I don't know the answer.